# Use Grails Form tag with Controller in Subfolder

Tags: grails

I'd like to send an email using a controller in a subfolder. I can't seem to find the syntax to accomplish this.

The default would be something like this...

```
<g:form controller="email" action="sendEmail">
     // form stuff
</g:form>
```

But my email controller, called Email.groovy, is in controllers/portal/Utils. Maybe this is outside normal convention?

Comment: what is the name of your controller?

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: Also, if you need to access the controller, or action, and it doesn´t  fit the normal convention , you can point to it directly using the [urlMapping](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Plug-ins/URL%20mappings.html) file.

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller class name to EmailController.groovy